# Error when trying to run Mailgun email with PHP

Tags: php, mailgun

I tried to test out the Mailgun API Sandbox to test out an email to myself. I downloaded the package that they suggested with the command line composer require `mailgun/mailgun-php kriswallsmith/buzz nyholm/psr7`, but when I tried to run my PHP file, this is the error I got:

```
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\ngeoy\Desktop\emailTest.php(5): Mailgun\Mailgun->__construct('f3701c5a4bb9615...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\ngeoy\Desktop\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun.php on line 55

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Mailgun\Mailgun::__construct() must be an instance of Mailgun\HttpClient\HttpClientConfigurator, string given, called in C:\Users\ngeoy\Desktop\emailTest.php on line 5 and defined in C:\Users\ngeoy\Desktop\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun.php:55
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\ngeoy\Desktop\emailTest.php(5): Mailgun\Mailgun->__construct('f3701c5a4bb9615...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\ngeoy\Desktop\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun.php on line 55
```

Does anyone know what I need to change, or how to resolve my code?

For reference, this is what my code looks like:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;
# Instantiate the client.
$mgClient = new Mailgun('f3701c5a4b************-a2b*****-aea*****');
$domain = "sandbox0dded5a4b2bd473da5fa99ba********.mailgun.org";
# Make the call to the client.
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
    'from'  => 'Excited User <randomemail@yahoo.com>',
    'to'    => 'Baz <anotherrandomemail@yahoo.com>',
    'subject' => 'Hello',
    'text'  => 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
));
?>
```

(The asterisks are obviously to hide private information)

Comment: Have a look at the examples in the documentation. They all use `Mailgun::create()` ~ https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#sending-via-api

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation at [GitHub](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php), you must use it as follows:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;

// First, instantiate the SDK with your API credentials
$mgClient = Mailgun::create('f3701c5a4b************-a2b*****-aea*****');
$domain = "sandbox0dded5a4b2bd473da5fa99ba********.mailgun.org";

// Now, compose and send your message.
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
    'from'  => 'Excited User <randomemail@yahoo.com>',
    'to'    => 'Baz <anotherrandomemail@yahoo.com>',
    'subject' => 'Hello',
    'text'  => 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
));
```